# Unable to cast object of type,

Tags: vb.net

This is my first post so I hope this is the right place and please be nice! Thanks.

So my issue is that I get an error while downloading a file. I have made a downloader app to download a specific file. It runs just fine until it hits the download complete event.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cmdDownload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdDownload.Click


    Try
        Dim webClient As New WebClient()
        AddHandler webClient.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler webClient.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client_DownloadFileCompleted
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wtdagv0xvliwvv2/viruslist.dat?dl=0"), Application.StartupPath + "\viruslist.dat")
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub client_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim bytesIn As Double = Double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString())
        Dim totalBytes As Double = Double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString())
        Dim percentage As Double = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100
        ProgBar.Value = Integer.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString())
        Label3.Text = "Total Complete " + ProgBar.Value.ToString + " %"
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub client_DownloadFileCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Database has finished downloading!", "Download Finished...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End Sub
```

The error I get is an

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast
>   object to type 'System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs' to type
>   'System.Net DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs', at
>   Database_Download.frm.Main._Lambda$__1(Object a0.
>   AsyncCompletedEventArgs a1)

Like I said all runs fine until it needs to fire the `DownloadComplete`, but it does not say my messagebox at all it just pops this error. I don't understand this because I have done this exact code in other projects without problems. 
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the signature. [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Public Sub client_DownloadFileCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
   MessageBox.Show("Database has finished downloading!", "Download Finished...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End Sub
```

Comment: That did the trick! That is weird, like I said this worked in other projects. Should I change it to this in other/future projects?

Comment: Just make sure they match. You should be able to see the signature when you hover over the events in the `Addhandler` statement.